# Spring Boot - how to keep JSESSIONID forever without session storage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

My goal is: keep JSESSIONID of a client forever, and store no session data on the server. Is it possible?

application.properties

```
spring.session.store-type=none
server.servlet.session.timeout=-1
```

This setup stores no session data, however JSESSIONID is replaced any time a new request is made after a server-restart. Is it possible to keep the JSESSIONID?

[image: Response Headers after server restart]

Comment: In today's world, especially for corporate businesses, the most common usage of authentication is the session-based approach. In the session-based approcah, a session id—which is a kind of server generated token—is generated and stored in a cookie within the JSESSIONID paramter. This means that the server stores the session key in itself so when the server reboots or requests are redirected to another server by load balancers, your "state" of session key becomes useless.

Comment: Sessions are useful without authentication too. As I understand the purpose is to store state between several HTTP requests.